# Z77 Motherboard with i7-2600K cpu, what will not work?

Tags: pci-express, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5, sandy-bridge, ivy-bridge

I'm building a new system. So far I think I narrowed it down to Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD5H (Z77 Ivy Bridge chipset) motherboard.

I was planning to get i5-3570K(Ivy Bridge) cpu, but now I can get i7-2600K(Sandy Bridge) cpu for free.

It is my understanding that Ivy Bridge platform brings support for PCIe3 and (additional?)USB3 ports.
If I were to put SB cpu into IB motherboard, what is going to happen to PCIe3 slot? Will it not work at all or downgrade to PCIe2? Also, what is the situation with USB3 ports?

Comment: If the motherboard supports the CPU, everything will work. PCIe ports may downgrade, but that's the worst problem you should have.

Comment: Motherboard does support this CPU. Well, that's why I'm asking to find out what exactly will happen..not what "may" happen. :)

Comment: It will work. That's what it means when a motherboard supports a CPU. :)

Comment: I know that it will "work". :) But I want to know what exactly will happen with PCIe3 slot so that I know what kind of videocard to buy and potentially to look for another motherboard that has more USB3 slots from auxiliary chipsets, not IB/cpu. This free cpu added yet another variable to my equation. :)

Comment: It has no effect on the USB ports. And it has no effect on which videocard you should buy.